# Skype version 8 moved the main.db file. Is there a way to read this database now?

Tags: skype

I need an app or method to read the main.db file now that skype converted me to version 8.xxx.  they moved the file to the skylib folder and I don't have any app now that can read the data.

Answer (score -1):

I used DB Browser for SqLite to open skype.db, which is the database file for the Skype App in Windows 10, and wrote sql queries to retrive the messages from the file.

I dont know the table schemes from the main.db for the 8.xx version, but it should be pretty similar.